# How to solve AccessDeniedException in AWS using Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin

Whenever I run this Kotlin code for AWS:

```
val request = AdminGetUserRequest().withUserPoolId("xxxxxx").withUsername("xxxxxxxx")
val client = AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().credentials)
val user = client.adminGetUser(request)
```

I get an AccessDeniedException. I've tried looking everywhere on how to grant access to a user to get attributes of another user but no luck. Is there even a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've figured it out and I'm leaving this for others if anyone needs help in the future. First you have to look up what role do your authenticated users acquire in your AWS Identity Pool. Then in the AWS Console go to your IAM service find that role and assign it a new Policy. Either CognitoPowerUser or CognitoReadOnly will do. After that use the code here:

```
    val request = AdminGetUserRequest().withUserPoolId("xxxxxxxx").withUsername("xxxxxxx")
    val client = AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().credentials)
    client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1))
    val foundUser = client.adminGetUser(request)
```

You have to manually set the region as it defaults to US_EAST_1 and my resources were in EU_CENTRAL_1. Keep in mind that a user must be logged in at this point in the app.